# HubSections Binding in UWP Hub

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to create a UWP app. I have a `Hub` with a large number of `HubSections`, so each section represents a day (first one being TODAY).

I don't know the number of `HubSections`, but they will all have the same content template.

I can't add anything to a `Hub`, other than HubSections. So `ItemsControl` is not an option.

How can I bind the Hub's `HubSections` in order to create as many as I want dynamically?

What I want to achieve:

```
<Hub ItemsSource={Binding MySectionData}>
  <DataTemplate>
     <!-- I would define the HubSection template here -->
  </DataTemplate>
</Hub>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I bind the Hub's HubSections in order to create as many as I want dynamically?

To create [`HubSections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hubsection) dynamically, you could simply create them code behind. Since all the `HubSections` have the same  `ContentTemplate` as you described, you can defined the `DataTemplate` in XAML and set the source to `ContentTemplate` of the `HubSection` when dynamically adding the `HubSection`.  For example:

XAML code:

```
<Page.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="FeaturedSectionTemplate">
       <Grid>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
               <RowDefinition Height="*" />
           </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
           <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" 
                      Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                      Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit nonumy sed consectetuer ising elit, sed diam"/>
           <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,0,0"
                      Text="Description text:"/>
           <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="3" 
                      Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer ising elit... "/>
       </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        HubSection s = new HubSection
        {
            Name = "name1",
            Header = "More...",
            //IsHeaderInteractive = true,
            Width = 500,
            Height = 420,
            ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["FeaturedSectionTemplate"]
        };
        MyHub.Sections.Add(s);
    }
}
```

More details please reference [Using a hub](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308518).